# Google OAuth Refresh Token irrevocable

Tags: curl, oauth, token, refresh-token

As per the documentation, if I revoke my access token refresh token will also get revoked.
I have a few questions.

1. Is it possible to make the refresh token irrevocable?
2. Can I make only the access token revokable?
3. Is it possible to make both refresh and access tokens irrevocable from the API? Can I put forbidden access?

[image]